# argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have this First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty issue with the form code of mine

i have defined in the controller as

```
   class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
  end
  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_params)
    @dashboard_user.save!
  end
  def user_creation

  end
  private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
  end
end
```

and for the form

```
<%= form_for @dashboard_user, url: "/admin/user_creation", method: "post" do |f| %>
```

but i am getting this error is there anywhere i did a mistake or i overlooked some basic things?

P.S i am redirecting to the same page after the form has been submitted

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin, :only => [:create, :new] do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
    get 'user_creation', on: :collection
    end
end
```

rake route

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
user_creation_admin_index POST /admin/user_creation(.:format) admin#user_creation
                          GET  /admin/user_creation(.:format) admin#user_creation
              admin_index POST /admin(.:format)               admin#create
                new_admin GET  /admin/new(.:format)           admin#new
                     root GET  /                              admin#new
```

Comment: Underscore. Seeing characters is a key debugging skill.

Comment: @RSB bro can you check this?

Comment: If you're "redirecting to the same page after the form has been submitted" then you'll need to provide more information. Is this error on the first time, or the second? To what *specifically* do you redirect to? What are the relevant routes? Etc.

Comment: this error happens when I open the link for the first time localhost:3000/admin/user_creation ..

Comment: Why would `new` even run with the routes you provide? Run `rake routes`--see the problem? Also, see how the additional information is *critical* to providing actionable advice?

Comment: added full controller code and rake routes ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i got the answer i need to use the controller action that corresponds to the view that contains my form .. my form is user_creation so i need to create a function 
def user_creation to make that work

```
def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_params)
    @dashboard_user.save!
  end
  def user_creation

  end
```

my view name is user_creation so changing the controller as below solved my issue

```
 def create

    end
    def user_creation
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_params)
    @dashboard_user.save!
    end
```